# High R for low frequency op amp integrator

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-pass, integrator

I have to design an integrator for very low frequencies (corner frequency around 0.5 Hz).

Are there any reasons why I cannot choose a really high resistor value (say 5M Ohm) to keep the capacitor value reasonably low?
Consider that the signals at play are also quite small.

Comment: You can use very high resistance values. There's no reason, necessarily, to avoid them. I don't consider 5 M to be high enough to worry much. I've used much higher. But at some point you must be careful. Boards that aren't absolutely pristine clean will have trace currents on their surfaces. So cleanliness starts to matter. Also, any voltages can develop currents on a board, as well. So actively driven guard traces can have a role at some point.

Comment: There are also times for board cutouts. If you open up a Keithley electrometer you will see these on display, prominently. And there are times when even the epoxy packaging of ICs get in the way. (Which will have about 10^11 Ohms between pins.) IC dice and wire bonding skills are needed then. That's from my own very limited experiences. I don't have a comprehensive enough view to offer an answer, though. So I'll leave that to the experts. But your currents must be fairly high (above a few tens of nanoamps.) Stuff only gets difficult below a picoamp, or so, at your frequency.

Comment: I mean, it does depend a bit on the input currents of your Opamp inputs. If you buy a somewhat, but not extremely, cheap modern CMOS opamp optimized for low frequencies (like, say, the LMC6442), you get currents on the inputs of 50 fA (that's femtoampere, 10⁻¹⁵ A). You can (theoretically) use Gigaohm resistors (but beware the points periblepsis raises above), then. Find the worst input bias current opamp on the market, and I'm sure even 100 kΩ resistors will be a problem

Comment: ("modern" above means "last 30 years")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5MΩ is not a very high value if your accuracy requirements are modest and the environment is benign. You normally don't start to run into problems with long time constants until the times get into the minutes. I have made analog products with time constants as high as 30 or 60 minutes. But that was then, now we would generally do that digitally once it gets beyond seconds.

You should pick an op-amp with a guaranteed low input bias current and a capacitor with guaranteed low leakage (neither of which are much of an issue for the numbers involved). And get a reasonably stable resistor.

I suggest also that you at least consider a digital solution, which can largely avoid the relatively large (relative to the accuracy of a crystal) temperature dependency of R and C values and several other sources of error.

Comment: and while you're already searching for opamps with low input bias current, note that there's special low gain-bandwidth-product opamps, especially for low-bandwidth smoothing applications, which might come with further properties beneficial to your situations (aside from the inherent high-frequency rejection), like very low supply currents and voltages, or very-close-to-rail output even at high or low output current draw.